# How do we find point( b ) on a graph at a specific angle from point( a ). Point( a ) being only value known.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems, geometric-construction

[image]

The origin is top-left here because I'm creating this image using [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics). The coordinate system starts in the top left and increases as you move down and/or right. I'm trying to find point *b* if the orange line is 60 degrees. The only information I have is point *a*.

**Note**: My end goal here is to construct an equilateral triangle.

**Edit:** Angle in picture isn't accurate.

Comment: Hint: Construct a horizontal line through point $b$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I don't know point ***b*** and the angle here isn't accurate. Just for visual understanding.

Comment: But you do know that line $ab$ will cross a horizontal line at $b$ at a $60^\circ$ angle. Let $c$ denote the point on the right side of the circle where the horizontal line through $b$ crosses. Then because of left-right symmetry of the circle, the line $ac$ will also cross the horizontal at a $60^\circ$ angle, and you will have an equilateral triangle $\triangle abc$. The vertices will be at angles $90^\circ, 150^\circ, 210^\circ$. You can use trigonometry to find the coordinates of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Interesting. I'll look into trigonometry. Not great at that lol.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $ a=50$

$$ ( x-a)^2+(y+a)^2=1 $$
$$y= \sqrt 3(x -a)$$

There are 2 equations and two variables, simplify and solve quadratic for $y$
$$ y^2/3+(y+a)^2=1 $$

Answer (score 1):

We can call define a vector at point $a$ that comes from the origin. Since it is at coordinate location $(50,0)$, it makes sense for the vector to be exactly $(50,0)^T$. Next, applying the rotation matrix (ie multiplying the above vector by the rotation matrix) with an angle of $60$ degrees (ie the angle you have above), we get the new point you desire, point $b$, at $(25,-25\sqrt{3})$.

It's clear this lies on the circle because the norm of the vector with these components equals $50$, which is the radius of your circle.

For more information on rotation matrix, see the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

IE, multiplying the vector:
\begin{bmatrix}50\\0\end{bmatrix} 
By the matrix: \begin{bmatrix}\cos(60)&-\sin(60)\\\sin(60)&\cos(60)
\end{bmatrix}

Will give you a new vector:

\begin{bmatrix}25\\-25\sqrt{3}\end{bmatrix}

Which holds the coordinates of the point $b$.

Comment: I like your answer, but watch out for radian vs degrees. I also think 60 degrees refers to the angle between the dotted line and axis instead of the rotation angle.

Comment: Don't know how I'm just seeing this now, but I believe you may be correct. The diagram is a little hard to make sense of in my defense! But I guess a 60 degree rotation would not put the point below the horizontal axis.Thanks for your input. At least the person below me answered it the other way.

Answer (score 1):

[image: equilateral triangle in circle]

Note that

$$ \frac{\vert df\vert}{\vert bf\vert}=\tan30^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

therefore

$$ \vert bf\vert=\sqrt{3}\,\vert df\vert $$

Furthermore,

\begin{eqnarray}\vert bf\vert^2+\vert df\vert^2&=&50^2\\
4\vert df\vert^2&=&50^2\\
\vert df\vert&=&25\\
\vert bf\vert&=&25\sqrt{3}
\end{eqnarray}

So

\begin{eqnarray}
b&=&(50+\vert df\vert,50-\vert bf\vert)\\
&=&(75,50-25\sqrt{3}
\end{eqnarray}

PS: Note that if you do not want to use $\tan30^\circ$, you can use the fact that $\triangle dbf$ is half of an equilateral triangle to get the proportion between sides $\vert bf\vert$ and $\vert df\vert$.